# Static vector pair of strings class member function

Tags: c++

> Write a function partlist that gives all the ways to divide a list (an array) of at least two elements into two non-empty parts.

From what I understand, the function should produce linear partitions (using term as mathematical) of the original array.

I think I understand each of the types for the function individually, but I am struggling to bring them all together.

(I have 6 months of C++ experience and no other languages. This is an exercise from codewars that I'm using to try to improve my coding skills)

I've written the function code up to the point where I want to start testing, but with the way the problem is worded, I do not understand how to instantiate the class type. I've reviewed statics, vectors, pairs, and constants in individual terms from class notes and cplusplus.com.

I've gotten to the point that the program will compile, but will not complete `main()`. I feel like I'm missing a vital bit of information, and I appreciate any help to understand the goal of the program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class PartList
{
public:
    static std::vector<std::pair <std::string, std::string>> partlist(std::vector<std::string> &arr);
};

///The above is what I have to work with///

int main(){
    std::vector<std::string> tester = {"I", "Love", "To", "Discrete"};
    PartList::partlist(tester);
}

std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> PartList::partlist(std::vector<std::string> &arr){
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> output;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,std::string>>::iterator bigIt = output.begin();
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator myIt;
    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator secIt = arr.begin();
        secIt != arr.end(); secIt++){
        myIt = arr.begin();
        while(myIt <= secIt){
            bigIt->first += *myIt;
            myIt++;
        }
        while((myIt > secIt) && myIt != arr.end()){
            bigIt->second += *myIt;
            myIt++;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Expected:

For `set {std::string a, std::string b, std::string c, std::string d}`

Should result in `{a, bcd}, {ab,cd}, {abc,d}`

Result:

nothing

Comment: I'm not sure about the details, but it's obvious that this code cannot work. When you declare it `output` has size zero. At no point does this change, yet you try to write to `output` using an iterator. This cannot work. You need to add elements to the vector by changing it's size, it doesn't grow automatically as you write to it. The simplest way is to use the `push_back` method.

Comment: ... and why are you creating a class with only a static function in it? Use a namespace or just let it be in the global namespace.

Comment: @Ted Looks to me like OP is given the class and has to create the function.

Comment: @JakobLovern Could be. The intro just mentions "_Write a function..._" but the comment in the code implies that the class and function declaration is given.

Comment: @Zachary: Regarding: "_I do not understand how to instantiate the class type_" - You don't need to. The class is pointless in this and your call to the static function `PartList::partlist(tester);` is fine except that you don't take care of what it returns (and even if you did, you haven't actually put anything in the returned vector). `bigIt->first = ...` and `bigIt->seond = ...` causes UB. `bigIt` points at `end()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As john said in comments. you're not actually *doing* anything with `output`. At the beginning of your `for` loop, you need to append a new item to `output` with `output.push_back()`. Then, instead of using an iterator, just reference that item using `output.back()`

code:

```
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::pair;

vector<pair<string, string>> PartList::partlist(vector<string> &arr)
{
    vector<pair<string, string>> output;
    vector<string>::const_iterator arr_iterator;

    for (vector<string>::const_iterator secIt = arr.begin(); secIt != std::prev(arr.end()); secIt++)
    {
        arr_iterator = arr.begin();
        output.push_back(pair<string, string>());
        while (arr_iterator <= secIt)
        {
            output.back().first += *(arr_iterator++);
        }
        while (arr_iterator != arr.end())
        {
            output.back().second += *(arr_iterator++);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: While you're at it, you could make `arr` const (and the relevant iterators `const_iterator`). The function is not supposed to change the strings in the original vector.

Comment: Should I? It would no longer compile, as OP's code specifies that `PartList::partlist` takes a `vector<string>`. Hrmm...

Comment: It's a very strange signature for a function in a programming test. I wonder if OP didn't come up with it after all. I'll compile fine if you make the relevant iterators into `const_iterator`.

Comment: Next you'll be telling me that I don't need the parentheses on `output.back()` and that `arr_iterator` can be post-incremented without worry...

Comment: :-) Well, I'd use for loops and pre increments (to avoid an unnecessary copy), like in `for(arr_iterator = arr.begin(); arr_iterator <= secIt; ++arr_iterator)` and `for(;arr_iterator != arr.end(); ++arr_iterator)`  but you got my +1.